# Laravel 6.x Relation hasOne with key in itself

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a relationship between `suppliers` and `supplierGroup`. One Supplier should have one Group. And one Group can have multiple suppliers.

The `suppliers` table has the key for the group in it.

```php
$table->integer("supplier_group_id")->nullable();
```

In my `supplier` model I have the following:

```php
public function supplierGroup(){
        return $this->belongsTo(SupplierGroup::class);
    }
```

and in my `supplierGroup` model:

```php
public function supplier(){
        return $this->hasMany(Supplier::class);
    }
```

When I then create a supplier and then a suppliergroup then they are not connected

```php
$supplier = \App\Models\Suppliers\Supplier::create([]);
$group = $supplier->supplierGroup()->create([]);
```

The field `supplier_group_id` will be left empty.

Did I forgot something or did I use the relations wrong?

Comment: @VincentDecaux when I use hasMany on the Supplier Model and belongTo in the supplier group then it throws the error that the field "supplier_id" does not exist in "supplier_groups". But if the "supplier_id" would be in the groups, then a group can only have one Supplier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `unsignedInteger` for foreign keys:

Change this:

`$table->integer("supplier_group_id")->nullable();`

To

`$table->unsignedInteger("supplier_group_id")->nullable();`

Also, don't forget to set the foreign key:

`$table->foreign('supplier_group_id')->reference('id')->on('supplier_groups');`

You can use the `save` method to set the supplier group

`$supplierGroup = new \App\Models\Suppliers\SupplierGroup()`

`$supplier->supplierGroup()->save($supplierGroup);`

Comment: didn't worked, I got many SQL errors. :/ but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

To connect a `supplier` with a `supplierGroup` you have to do the following:

```
$group = \App\Models\Suppliers\SupplierGroup::create([]);
        $supplier = \App\Models\Suppliers\Supplier::create([]);
        $supplier->supplierGroup()->associate($group)->save();
```

Creating doesn't work that way (it's also unnecessary).